# Limit file size for FFMPEG AV Stats

Tags: logs, raspbian, ffmpeg

I'm doing this with ffmpeg...

```
nohup ffplay -reorder_queue_size 0 -nostats -i /tmp/stl-app/stream.sdp -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,udp,rtp" -nodisp -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level &> /tmp/stl-app/stream-stats.log &
```

The problem I'm running in to is that I have tmpfs drive setup with 100M of free space. I'm burning through that in about 90 mins. I've tried echoing a blank file to the stream-stats.log and just deleting it. But because of the way that FFMPEG writes to it, if I delete it, it just doesn't write to that any more. I need a way to clear the file every x mins or at least limit it to a manageable size that I can keep reading from.

I really only need an update every second or so and I don't need to keep the file obviously. What's the right way to handle this?

UPDATE
Based on a commend from @gyan I created a pipe at /tmp/stl-app/icecaststats and then reran my command like

```bsh
nohup ffplay -reorder_queue_size 0 -nostats -i /tmp/stl-app/stream.sdp -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,udp,rtp" -nodisp -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level > /tmp/stl-app/icecaststats &
```

But I'm not getting any data there for some reason?

Comment: Create a file using mkfifo and write to that. Whatever's read from there will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

So a working solution for me was to update the -af flag

```bsh
ffplay -autoexit -nodisp -f mp3 -i $ICECASTURL -af asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level
```

Setting asetnsamples tells ffplay how big of a sample size you want. Since I'm running audio at 44100Hz I set the sample size to that and thus it only updates every second. Drastically reducing the file size that I'm logging to.